# Is JSON or XML more performant on iOS?

Tags: php, ios, xml, json

I am developing a game for the iOS (and later for Android) devices which needs to get data from a database on a server. What I have done so far is to use PHP to echo out the data from the database as XML. The program will check often with the server so performance is a big deal here. So, would JSON or XML be better for this task?

Answer (score 2):

Produce XML output. Check the time taken and the file size.

Produce JSON output. Check the time taken and the file size.

Decide which is best.

Answer (score 0):

Better depends on your case. For your case it could be JSON. It's light and easy to parse in Javascript (if you'll use it with JS)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is good.

"the program will check often with the server". That is not required I believe.

Send an Asynchronous request using NSURLConnection and use NSNotificationCenter for notification services of iOS. So, when you get a response from the server, you can set a function to be called to use the data you need. [Check here for NSNotificationCenter usage](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html)